# Adding the numbers created in a while loop python

Tags: python, list

```
repeat1=0 
while repeat1!=x1:
    fini=ord(dlist[repeat1])
    repeat1=repeat1+1
    print (fini)
sum_of_all=sum(fini)
print(sum_of_all)
```

i want to add the numbers that are made from the variable fini.
python gives me an error saying: 'int' is not iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a *list* of those numbers. You are instead just assigning each number to `fini` without doing anything with the preceding numbers:

```
values = []
while repeat1 != x1:
    fini = ord(dlist[repeat1])
    values.append(fini)
    repeat1 = repeat1 + 1

sum_of_all = sum(values)
```

You may as well just sum the values in the loop however:

```
sum_of_all = 0
while repeat1 != x1:
    fini = ord(dlist[repeat1])
    sum_of_all += fini
    repeat1 = repeat1 + 1

print(sum_of_all)
```